# My PHP isn't working but doesn't return any errors

Tags: php, html

For whatever reason my PHP doesn't seem to do anything?
I'm not getting errors or anything it just doesn't do anything.

This is my code: I tried to put a header but it just didn't do anything
I'm using xampp and accessing it with http:// not with file://
here's my PHP code.

```
<?php 
if(!(isset($_POST['submit']))) {
    session_start();
    $firstimgsrc = $_POST['firstimgsrc'];   
    if ($firstimgsrc == "") {
        echo "w/e";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['firstimgsrc'] = $firstimgsrc;
    }
    $secondimgsrc = $_POST['secondimgsrc'];
    if ($secondimgsrc == "") {
        echo "w/e"; } else {
        $_SESSION['secondimgsrc'] = $secondimgsrc;

    }
    $thirdimgsrc = $_POST['thirdimgsrc'];

    if ($thirdimgsrc == "") {
        echo "w/e";
    } else {
    $_SESSION['thirdimgsrc'] = $thirdimgsrc;
}
    $forthimgsrc = $_POST['forthimgsrc'];
    if ($forthimgsrc == "") {
        echo "w/e";

    } else {
        $_SESSION['forthimgsrc'] = $forthimgsrc;
    }
    header("Location: ../egamingtv.php");
}

?>
```

and the partial html code:

```
<form method="post" action="changecontent.php">
                <div class="champs">

                    <img id="firstimg" src="">
                    <input name="firstimgsrc">
                    <input id="firstchamp" value="" style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px;" disabled="yes">
                    <input id="firstdate" style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px;"  value="" disabled="yes"></div>
                <div class="champs">
                    <img id="secondimg" src="">
                    <input name="secondimgsrc">
                    <input id="secondchamp" style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px;"  value="" disabled="yes">
                    <input id="seconddate" style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px;" value="" disabled="yes">
                </div>
                <div class="champs">
                    <img id="thirdimg" src="">
                    <input name="thirdimgsrc">
                    <input id="thirdchamp" style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px;"  value="" disabled="yes">
                    <input id="thirddate" style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px;"  value="" disabled="yes"></div>
                <div class="champs">
                    <img id="forthimg" src="">
                    <input name="forthimgsrc">
                    <input id="forthchamp" style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px;"  value="" disabled="yes">
                    <input id="forthdate" style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px;"  value="" disabled="yes">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" >
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: What is the expected output and what do you actually get?

Comment: @Deception don't do what you did here. Leave your question text what it was, and let the site handle the question closing. *Or* delete your question if it was a trivial problem that could have been avoided being asked with a little more time (or if it wasn't trivial but had an easy fix: post the answer yourself). The one thing you should *not* do is edit your post to suddenly not have any text in it anymore. In this case you had an answer that solved your problem: upvote and accept that. (and let 'closing' as voted by the SO community just happen. No need to take it into account)

Answer (score 3):

See this line here,

```
if(!(isset($_POST['submit']))) { 
   ^ see this NOT sign
```

The `if` statement should be like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```